# Android setAnimation firing directly

Tags: android, android-animation

Hello I am using the following:

```
        final ImageView ivLoading3 = new ImageView(context);
        ivLoading3.setBackgroundResource(com.example.testtabswipe.R.drawable.dot_loading);
        ivLoading3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        final TranslateAnimation mAnimation3 = new LoadingTranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.2f);
        ((LinearLayout) view).addView(ivLoading3);
        ivLoading3.setAnimation(mAnimation3); // <--- firing off directly
```

I wish for this not to fire directly. Is there something I'm missing?

As I understand it startAnimation is used to fire directly and setAnimation just sets it but does not fire it. Something I misunderstood here?

From the official document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation):

> public void setAnimation (Animation animation)
>   Sets the next animation to play for this view. If you want the
>   animation to play     immediately, use
>   startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation) instead.  This method
>   provides allows fine-grained control over the start time and
>   invalidation, but you must make sure that 1) the animation has a start
>   time set, and 2) the view's parent (which controls animations on its
>   children) will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to start.

Comment: I didn't understand what are you asking for clearly, can you explain more what do you mean by directly and firing ?

Comment: When my view loads the Animation fires, afaiac I should use ivLoading3.startAnimation(mAnimation3) and not ivLoading3.setAnimation(mAnimation3) if I want to fire the animation directly onload. Is there something I misunderstood between the both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **setAnimation**
>
> Sets the next animation to play for this view.But view animation does
> not start yet.
>
> **startAnimation**
>
> If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation.
> This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time
> and invalidation, but you must make sure that
>
> 1. the animation has a start time set,
> 2. the view will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to
>    start.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910033/1932105)

Comment: Exactly! However I am using setAnimation and it is firing off directly.

Comment: try using .stop after setting the animation, and when wanting the animation start it by .start

Comment: Unfortunetly there is no stop method to invoke :/

Comment: You can also call anim.cancel(); but you should also call anim.reset(); immediately after it. Then when you want to start it again, just call startAnimation on the view.

Comment: Bingo! invoking cancel() then reset() made it act correctly. A hack though unfortunetly.

Comment: dont call cancel() & reset() just call setStartTime(Integer.MAX_VALUE) if you want to start it leter

Comment: Damn! I'm using API14 and .cancel(),.reset() way not worked. The only way worked for me was the pskink's. But I found it tricky as the max value for long can be reached in some time.  And idk if it's not consuming memory as the time count is running in background, is it? Is it relevant?

Answer (score 0):

use anim.setStartTime before calling view.setAnimation(anim), see also AnimationUtil.currentAnimationTimeMillis()

Comment: What value for setStartTime? I tried -1 and 0, still firing :/

Comment: AnimationUtil.currentAnimationTimeMillis() for now

Comment: so add another 5000 if you want to start it in 5 seconds